# JPQL query for many to many relationship where item does not exist in join table

Tags: java, sql, jpa, many-to-many

I'm trying to construct a JPQL query to select only VMs that do not exist in a Group. I have a many to many relationship between VMs and Groups:

class Group:

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(
     name="group_vm",
     joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="vm_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 private Set<VM> vms;
```

This is fairly easy in SQL:

select * from vm where id not in (select vm_id from group_vm);

Is there a way to do this in JPQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NOT EXISTS

```
select vm from VM vm where not exists (select 1 from Group gr where vm member of gr.vms)
```

NOT IN should also work, but exists may be faster

```
select vm from VM vm where vm not in (select gr.vms from Group gr)
```